# WebAPI Return JSON array without root node

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following sample code in an EmployeeController that creates a couple of employees, adds them to an employee list, and then returns the employee list on a get request.  The returned JSON from the code includes Employees as a root node.  I need to return a JSON array without the Employees property because whenever I try to parsethe JSON result to objects I get errors unless I manually reformat the string to not include it.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeList
{
    public EmployeeList()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    public EmployeeList Get()
    {
        EmployeeList empList = new EmployeeList();
        Employee e1 = new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = 1,
            Name = "John",
            Position = "CEO"
        };
        empList.Employees.Add(e1);
        Employee e2 = new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = 2,
            Name = "Jason",
            Position = "CFO"
        };
        empList.Employees.Add(e2);

        return empList;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON result I receive when the controller is called

```
{
    "Employees":
        [
           {"EmployeeID":1,"Name":"John","Position":"CEO"},     
           {"EmployeeID":2,"Name":"Jason","Position":"CFO"}
        ]
}
```

This is the JSON result that I need returned

```
[
    {"EmployeeID":1,"Name":"John","Position":"CEO"},     
    {"EmployeeID":2,"Name":"Jason","Position":"CFO"}
]
```

Any help is much appreciated as I am new to WEBAPI and parsing the JSON results

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What is the code that's calling the API?  I would look more at refactoring the client code parsing rather than trying to much around with the default behavior, it looks like your API code is pretty simple, I'd keep it that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens because you are not actually returning a `List<Employee>` but an object (EmployeeList) that has a `List<Employee>` in it.
Change that to return `Employee[]` (an array of Employee) or a mere `List<Employee>` without the class surrounding it

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning a list but an object with embedded list in it. Change a signature of your method to:

```
public List<Employee> Get()
```

And then return only list:

```
return empList.Employees;
```