# How to move JSON object's depth one level up in JSON.net using C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to write a converter for a class using JSON.net

When I serialize the object of type `JsonObject`, I get the following output

```
{"DataObject":{"id":"1","name":"data name"}}
```

How can I move the `DataObject` one level up to get the following output:

```
{"id":"1","name":"data name"}
```

You can find the relevant code below.

My class has the following format:

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public JsonObject(IDataObject dataObject)
    {
        this.DataObject= dataObject;
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDataObjectConverter))]
    public IDataObject DataObject;
}
```

The `DataObject` has some properties:

```
public class MyDataObject : IDataObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I referred [this page](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) from the documentation and wrote the following converter:

```
public class JsonDataObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDataObject).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType.GetTypeInfo());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is MyDataObject dataObject)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("id");
            writer.WriteValue(dataObject.Id);
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            writer.WriteValue(dataObject.Name);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can see how you're getting the level, but I am wondering why you want to remove it? It

Comment: The application to which the JSON will be sent expects it to be without that extra level.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007512/webapi-return-json-array-without-root-node

Comment: I checked it. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide any help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired output by moving the converter to the class instead of the property and ignoring the property using `[JsonIgnore]`. The property needs to be ignored since the converter for the class will generate the JSON for the property as shown below.

So the `JsonObject` class will be:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectConverter))]
public class JsonObject
{
    public JsonObject(IDataObject dataObject)
    {
        this.DataObject= dataObject;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IDataObject DataObject;
}
```

Then create the converter like this:

```
public class JsonObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDataObject).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType.GetTypeInfo());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)value;
        if (jsonObject.DataObject.GetType() == typeof(MyDataObject))
        {
            MyDataObject dataObject = (MyDataObject) jsonObject.DataObject;

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("id");
            writer.WriteValue(dataObject.Id);
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            writer.WriteValue(dataObject.Name);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the desired output of:

```
{"id":"1","name":"data name"}
```